# Why super class method being called here?

Tags: java, inheritance, private, overriding

this is my code

```
class Hello{
    void method(){
        System.out.println("super method");
        meth();
    }
    private void meth(){
        System.out.println("sup meth");
    }
}
public class HelloWorld extends Hello{
    //@Override - would fail as meth is private in Hello
    protected void meth(){
        System.out.println("sub meth");
    }
    protected void method(){
        super.method();
    }
     public static void main(String []args){
        new HelloWorld().method();
     }
}
```

the returned result is

```
super method
sup meth
```

but why ? shouldn't it instead print

```
super method
sub meth
```

if I were to write `meth` method as public in `Hello` and override it in `HelloWorld`

result wud be abovementioned one. 
`meth` invocation from `method` still invokes `meth` of sub class , even though the meth invocation is inside super class , lexically speaking ! 
So why different behavior when `meth` is private ?

**_____________Edit_____________**

Had the code been something like this

```
class Hello{
    void method(){
        System.out.println("super method");
        meth();
    }
    protected void meth(){
        System.out.println("sup meth");
    }
}
public class HelloWorld extends Hello{
    //@Override - would fail as meth is private in Hello
    protected void meth(){
        System.out.println("sub meth");
    }
    protected void method(){
        super.method();
    }
     public static void main(String []args){
        new HelloWorld().method();
     }
}
```

the o/p would be

```
super method
sub meth
```

So, even though `method` in super class `Hello` is invoking `meth` , actually sub class's `meth` is being called . So , method invocation is not in the lexical sense ! i.e even if it seems the super class's meth will be invoked, its actually subclass's becoz subclass instance invoked `method` in the first place.
why things differnt when `meth` private in super class

Answer (score 3):

You cannot override a private method as the compiler tells you. So the only meth() the super class knows about is its own.

You cannot override a private method as it is internal to the class, so its subclasses do not even know its super's private methods exist.

Comment: I agree ! but still even when the control is inside the super class, its the subclass object thats calling the shots . Thats why had the method been something other than private, the sub class method version would have been invoked. Now in this case, as u said , private superclass method is not even known to exist by subclass instance. So it wud have been natural if subclass instance actually invoked subclass meth() albeit from inside the superclass method.
please clarify if my concept is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your method `meth()` is `private` and the subclass has no access to it.

Comment: I agree ! but still even when the control is inside the super class, its the subclass object thats calling the shots . Thats why had the method been something other than private, the sub class method version would have been invoked. Now in this case, as u said , private superclass method is not even known to exist by subclass instance. So it wud have been natural if subclass instance actually invoked subclass meth() albeit from inside the superclass method.
please clarify if my concept is wrong

Answer (score 0):

The Super class is calling meth() from itself, and thus, it is looking for this.meth(). The super doesn't even know about the subclass's meth() because 1) It is in a subclass, 2) The subclasses method is private.

I would recommend reading up on inheritance:
[Java Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)